# Want to be able to set the default field values that should be shown in a multi-select list rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, rails-admin

I have the following model

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaign_rules
  has_many :campaign_details
  validates_presence_of [:start_at, :end_at]

  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :slug
      field :start_at
      field :end_at
      field :is_active
      fields :campaign_rules do
        searchable :slug
      end
      fields :campaign_details
    end
  end
end
```

in my view, i get the following when i want to say create a new campaign. [image]

But in my campaign_rules model, i have a field called `slug` which i would prefer to be shown as the default text in the associated record in the multi-select list. So for example for CampaignRule #1 , slug name is `campaign-1` and i would prefer in my multi-select list to show `campaign-1` instead of `CampaignRule #1`.

How can i do this?

I also want to be able to make sure that the multi-select dropdown list shown is based on associated campaign_id. Currently in my multi-select dropdown, it shows all records of the `CampaignRule` even though there is an association with campaign. How do i configure this as well?

Comment: can you add the code of your view and possibly your controller as well, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default rails admin uses the name attribute of an instance to display them.

You can tell rails admin what method to use adding this line on the initializer config file.

```
RailsAdmin.config {|c| c.label_methods << :rails_admin_title }
```

And then you would implement that instance method on your tag model

```
class CampaignRaule < ApplicationRecord
   def rails_admin_title
      self.slug
   end 
end
```

As to how customize the records on the multi-select dropdown you can filter them with a regular ActiveRecord scope like this:

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :campaign_rules do
        associated_collection_scope do
          associated_collection_scope do
            campaign = bindings[:object]

            proc { |scope| scope.where(campaign: campaign) }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```